# Is there any workaround to run JRE apps on android?

Tags: android, java

Is there any work around to run web pages which are supported by JRE, in Android ?

example 1 : http://deploy.virtual-labs.ac.in/labs/cse15/exp4/exp4.html

example 2 : keepvid.com

Comment: No.. there isnt any ..

Answer (score 1):

looks like there is one coming soon: http://www.apogee.com/products/cjre-a

> The first JRE4A scheduled for release in mid march 2014 is targeted
>   at wireless and “connected” devices based on ARM Cortex-A8, Cortex-A9,
>   Cortex-A15, or similar ARM processors running Android 4.1.x, 4.2.x,
>   4.3.x, or 4.4, such as smart phones, tablets, other "hand-helds", home gateways, etc.  The JRE4As targeted at devices based on x86, MIPS, and
>   PowerPC processors running Android 4.2.x, 4.3.x, 4.4, or a subsequent
>   release of Android would follow in 2nd quarter of 2014.
>
> This first
>   JRE4A will be available for download from Google Play as a single
>   Android-compatible “.apk” file, which will run, after installed on a
>   given Android device, side-by-side with its Android on “top” of its
>   Android-specific Linux while utilizing relevant native libraries that
>   come with Android.  This means that each Android device having the
>   “.apk” of JRE4A installed on it will be fully capable of executing JAR
>   (Java ARchive) files of Java SE 5, SE 6 or SE 7 applications, in
>   addition to still being fully capable of executing DEX (Dalvik
>   EXecutable) files of Android applications.  That would, for example,
>   benefit the users of Android devices who have existing Java SE
>   application developed for devices running Linux or other operating
>   systems, because they could continue to use such applications on their
>   Android devices without having to convert a JAR file of each such
>   application to a DEX file, which is difficult to do and often results
>   in a DEX file of poor runtime performance.